# Is there a way to save a Treeview's items and data so it can be accessed in a thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, treeview

A TreeView item and data holds a filename and the data holds a TBitmap.  My question pertains to somehow saving the items and the data in the treeview so the items and data can be accessed in a thread.   If this is possible, after saving items and data, I could access the items and data in the thread rather than accessing it in Synchronize. As the code written now is too slow because of accessing the GUI TreeItems and Data in Synchronize.

```
if not Terminated then
begin
   Synchronize(
   procedure
   var
     i: integer;
   begin
     for i := 1 to Form1.TreeView1.Items.Count - 1 do
     begin
        { get the bitmap }
        iImageEnIO.WIAParams.ProcessingBitmap := iImageEnIO.IEBitmap;
        { The following line prevents me from accessing the TreeView data in a thread }
        iImageEnIO.WIAParams.Transfer(TIEWiaItem(Form1.TreeView1.Items[i].Data), False);
        { Set the filename }
        iFilename := Form1.TreeView1.Items[i].Text + '.jpg';
        { Add the image to the iIEImageList }
        iIndex := iIEImageList.AppendImageRef(TIEBitmap.Create(iImageEnIO.IEBitmap), iFileName);
        iIEImageList.Filename[iIndex] := iFileName;
     end;
end);
```

The threads code to access the bitmaps in the thread itself works very well, but if I can move the code that gets the bitmap to the thread rather than in Synchronize would be much better.  So my question is "Is there ay way to save a treeview items and data in Synchronize so it can be accessed in the thread outside of Synchronize"?

```
    iImageEnIO.OnProgress := ImageEnProcProgress;
    iImageEnIO.OnFinishWork := ImageEnProcFinishWork;

    { Get the bitmap from the imagelist and save the image in the thread }
    iCount := iIEImageList.ImageCount;
    for j := 0 to iCount-1 do
       begin
         { get the filename from the string list }
         iFilename := iIEImageList.Filename[j];
         { attach the iIEBitmap2 to iImageEnIO }
         iImageEnIO.AttachedIEBitmap := iIEImageList.Image[j];
         iPath := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(iFolder) + iFilename;
         iImageEnIO.SaveToFile(iPath); 
      end;
```

I hope I have asked my question correctly and it is clear what I would like to try to do.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, no I do not need to access the bitmaps after saving.  I just need to be able to access the node items to get the filename and to add the bitmap to the iIEImageList before saving the file to disk in the thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to turn this on its head. You want to know how to read the data from the GUI control when executing your thread method. That is a fundamental design flaw. The solution to your problem will involve not attempting to do that at all.

The tree view should not be the owner of the data. It is a GUI control and should merely present a view of the data. The data should be held in a structure that is not bound to the VCL threading rules. Once you have the data structure separated from the GUI, your problem becomes trivial. Once you reach that point, there is no problem to be solved.

So, what kind of a structure do you need? Although it is stored in a tree view, it appears to be a flat list. Store it in a `TList<T>` container. What do you use for `T`? Well, that's just the information needed for each item. That could be a record. Or it could be a class. If you are holding non-value type objects in the item type, then a class is probably better. In which case `TObjectList<T>` is a better fit. So, it would look like this:

```
type
  TItem = class
  private
    FFileName: string;
    FBitmap: TBitmap;
  end;
```

Then your container is simply `TObjectList<TItem>`. Instantiate it like this:

```
FItems := TObjectList<TItem>.Create(True);
```

The `True` is for the `OwnsObjects` parameter. This means that when you delete items from the container, or delete the container, the items are destroyed.

At this point you are able to populate the tree view by iterating over the container, and creating nodes to represent the items.

Then when your thread needs to operate on the data, it can refer to `FItems` which is separated from the GUI control.

The moral of the story is that you should not use your GUI controls as your primary data containers.

Comment: Is FItems defined as TItem?

Comment: No. Look at how it is instantiated. It is `TObjectList<TItem>`

Comment: Uses Contnrs;
TItem = class(TObjectList)
  private
    FFileName: string;
    FIEBitmap: TIEBitmap;
  end;

Comment: TFileSavingThread = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FItem: TObjectList<TItem>;

Comment: My answer assumes generics. Are you using a legacy Delphi? Why would you use Contnrs? And why would you derive TItem from a list? It is an item and not a container. My answer doesn't derive from a container

Comment: TObjectList is not defined.  Sorry never worked with object lists before.

Comment: Good. Don't ever use Contnrs. Use Generics.Collections instead. And TItem is a single item. Corresponds to a node in your tree.

Comment: I guess you'll need to get up to speed with generic containers then.

Comment: With containers, TItem = class(TObjectList) is undefined

Comment: My code doesn't look like that. Look how I defined TItem. You will need to learn about containers before you can expect to use them.

Comment: Can you add a little more code to your answer to get me off on the right foot.  iImageEnIO.WIAParams.ProcessingBitmap := iImageEnIO.IEBitmap;
                FItem.Add(iFilename);
                { Set the bitmap }
                FItem.Add(iImageEnIO.IEBitmap);

Comment: I don't know your details. My answer is by necessity high level. It is a conceptual answer. If you don't know the generic containers, you've got to master them first.

Comment: BRAVO for your answer, David!